# HTML TBODY and yes... IE

Tags: css, html

OK... it's about our friend IE 10 and below.

I have the fiddle, but it works in the fiddle, in chrome, firefox and TP.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gloak/F4hH9/). Nothing to fix in the fiddle, because result is as expected. 
Here is a piece of the code, a full tbody:

```
<tbody class="subdivision">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="color:red">Open House</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="label">Date:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="day" value="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>">
            </td>
            <td>Time:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="hours" value="<?php echo $row['hours']; ?>">
            </td>
            <td>price:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

In IE, tbody wraps every single cell ( < td > )
Question: how to make tbody in IE to wrap several < tr>'s.

Thank you so much for your time in advance.

PS. I am new to computers, maybe I did something wrong and it worked and I want it to work in IE too....

Comment: Have you tried `cellpadding="10"` instead of `cellspacing="10"` ?

Comment: Well, that seems to be answer, even though the squares look kind of crazy. I will work on the CSS. Please put as an answer because it's in the right direction! Thank you!

Comment: The title should clearly state what the problem is, and the content of the question should start with a more detailed description of what is expected and what actually happens. “To wrap several < tr>'s” is a vague expression and does not express the expectation about outlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `cellpadding` to give more padding to content *inside of the cell*, because *cellspacing* is used for space *between cells*.

But a much better approach, as you gathered, is not to use these attributes at all and do this completely with CSS.

Comment: I agree. Thank you so much! Also, there should be a universal law banning IE10 and below. We spend so much time with IE...

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: After some deeper research I withdraw my original answer. According to Html5 spec, the tbody element is an HTMLCollection and multiple can be appended to a table via the DOM method createTBody().

I've never tried styling a tbody as I don't use them at all, but perhaps you can work-around the problem by using all rows and creating the subheadings with colspans.

Comment: this is wrong.  you can only have one `thead` or `tfoot`, but as many `tbody` as you like.  note the difference in phrasing on the `thead` and `tfoot` pages.

Comment: Navigating the W3 site is quite tough. I didn't see it the first time through, but updated my answer, which is more of a work-around. I have to admit, I've never seen anyone use multiple tbody elements in a table.

Comment: i've done it before to handle alternating row colors in the presence of `rowspan`.  not sure what other use cases there are really